# I can't install expo-cli

Tags: react-native, npm, vue-native

When I install `expo-cli` with `npm i -g expo-cli` I get thousands of `npm WARN tar invalid entry`, and then I get this error :

> npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\mrkinix\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\bunyan\bin\bunyan
> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall chmod npm
> ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod
> 'C:\Users\mrkinix\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\bunyan\bin\bunyan'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\mrkinix\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-15T14_11_31_669Z-debug.log
>
> 35648 error path C:\Users\mrkinix\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-tools\node_modules\lodash
> 35649 error code ENOENT  35650 error errno -4058 35651 error syscall rename  35652 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
> 'C:\Users\mrkinix\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-tools\node_modules\lodash'
> -> 'C:\Users\mrkinix\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-tools\node_modules.lodash.DELETE'
> 35653 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.  35654 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

Comment: Add in question version of you os

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with npm install -g expo-cli, having "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",

I installed yarm with brew, just in case you do not already have it:

```
brew install yarn
```

and then use:

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

to create a project you can:

```
expo init nameOfTheNewProject
```

and choose a template in the console.
Finally run the project with

```
yarn start
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: you answer is for Mac OS, Linux and Windows 10 (with Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Answer (score 1):

1.run "npm update -g" update all npm global packages.

2.run "yarn add global expo-cli"

3.uninstall exop cli > clean npm cache folder, .expo folder install install again

Answer (score 1):

Delete these files ['expo.ps1' , 'expo-cli.ps1'] in this path:

'C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Roaming\npm'

then run:

npm i -g expo-cli