# Can't install expo-cli --global

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I was trying to install expo globally on my windows 7 (AMD processor) 
I used `npm install expo-cli --global` this command 
after few warnings i got this **"WARN tar ENOENT : no such file or directory , ope"**
and I have waited for more than 30 minutes, even though installation is still running but not installing

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794015/i-cant-install-expo-cli) but nothing happened, sorry if i did any mistake in asking the question because this is my first question here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Run the command in verbose mode to see full debug log. `npm install expo-cli --global --verbose`. If you still can't figure out, please add the output of this command with verbose in your question.

Comment: @Shumail thanks a lot it worked , but before doing this i installed latest version of node.js before i had installed node version: 10.14.1

Answer (score 0):

try this in your terminal

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

or

```
npm install expo-cli --global --verbose
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clear -f
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it